# Separating SQL database record insertion and program logic

Tags: c#, sql, database

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    private class DataAccess
    {
        private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseServerInstance"].ConnectionString;
        public static void Push(object o)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                switch (o)
                {
                    case Billing billing:
                        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BILLINGS (Comission Sales, Takedown Fee, Extra Billings)" +
                                                         "VALUES(@ComissionSales,@TakedownFee,@BillingExtra)", connection);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@ComissionSales", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = billing.ComissionSales;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@TakedownFee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = billing.TakedownFee;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@BillingExtra", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = billing.BillingExtra;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        break;
                    case Renter renter:
                        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RENTERS (Name, Phone, Email, BankAccount)" +
                                                         "VALUES(@RenterName,@RenterPhone,@RenterEmail,@RenterPaymentinfo)", connection);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@RenterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = renter.RenterName;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@RenterPhone", SqlDbType.Int).Value = renter.RenterPhone;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@RenterEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = renter.RenterEmail;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@RenterPaymentinfo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = renter.RenterPaymentinfo;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        break;
                    case Booking booking:
                        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BOOKINGS (Booking Paid, Weeks, Start Date, End Date)" +
                                                         "VALUES(@v,@IsPaid,@BookingStartdate,@BookingEnddate)", connection);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@IsPaid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = booking.IsPaid;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@BookingWeeks", SqlDbType.Int).Value = booking.BookingWeeks;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@BookingStartdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = booking.BookingStartdate;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@BookingEnddate", SqlDbType.Int).Value = booking.BookingEnddate;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        break;
                    case Shelf shelf:
                        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SHELVES (Shelf ID, Rented)" +
                                                         "VALUES(@ShelfID,@IsBooked)", connection);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@ShelfID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = shelf.ShelfID;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@IsBooked", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shelf.IsBooked;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I go about separating my `switch(o)` from my class only passing a SQL statement as a string instead? I am pushing out active records from instantiated objects, so a string name, e.g., `"INSERT INTO BILLINGS"` could easily be passed, but how would I then execute the `Parameters.Add` to convert the object into a record without using logic inside my `DataAccess` class without it knowing the type of object?

Comment: It feels like you want polymorphism here. Is something like the command pattern appropriate?

Comment: @ndc85430 I am still learning although this is what I was thinking of. I was thinking of passing the `INSERT INTO` as a string value along with the object, but the `DataAccess` would still need to identify the type of object before being able to create the record. Could I perhaps overload the methods to fit each type and then call them by a delegate instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of object orientation paradigms and let the objects create their queries by themselves.

Therefore, each of these classes should inherit the same base class containing abstract methods for Creating the specific sql command.

I prepared a very crude example for you just for the Billing class:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseServerInstance"].ConnectionString;
    public static void Push(BasePersistable o)
    {
        using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        var command = o.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

class Billing : BasePersistable
{
    public string CommissionSales { get; set; }
    public int TakedownFee { get; set; }
    public string BillingExtra { get; set; }

    public override SqlCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SomeSql");
        command.Parameters.Add("@ComissionSales", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CommissionSales;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TakedownFee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TakedownFee;
        command.Parameters.Add("@BillingExtra", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = BillingExtra;
        return command;
    }
}

public abstract class BasePersistable
{
    public abstract SqlCommand CreateCommand();
}
```

Hope this might help you!

Comment: This is a great answer! I decided, though, to contain all the SQL commands within the `DataAccess` class, but polymorphed the method `Push` to suit each of my separate objects. The corresponding classes, whose types fit the `Push` method, have a method called `Create`, which then checks the type of object and passes it on to `DataAccess` for final SQL query execution. By doing this I can also control if the object will be valid for insertion and throw an exception if it is not

Answer (score 0):

One option is to encapsulate the Command building in the specific object
Something like

```
interface ICommandBuilder
{
  SqlCommand GenerateCommand(SqlConnection connection);
}

class Billing : ICommandBuilder
{
  SqlCommand GenerateCommand(SqlConnection connection)
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BILLINGS (Comission Sales, Takedown Fee, Extra Billings)" +
                    "VALUES(@ComissionSales,@TakedownFee,@BillingExtra)", connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ComissionSales", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = billing.ComissionSales;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@TakedownFee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = billing.TakedownFee;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@BillingExtra", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = billing.BillingExtra;
    return command;
  }
}

public static void Push(ICommandBuilder o)
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = o.GenerateCommand(connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```